# How to define recursive variadic macros?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2012, macros, variadic-macros

I am trying to convert boolean values, which represent bits of a signal bus, into an integer. I am using the following construct:

```
#define B_TO_UINT1(b00)      (((uint32_t) b00 << 0))
#define B_TO_UINT2(b01, ...) (((uint32_t) b01 << 1) | B_TO_UINT1(__VA_ARGS__))
#define B_TO_UINT3(b02, ...) (((uint32_t) b02 << 2) | B_TO_UINT2(__VA_ARGS__))
#define B_TO_UINT4(b03, ...) (((uint32_t) b03 << 3) | B_TO_UINT3(__VA_ARGS__))
// ...
```

When using the macro cascade to convert a 1-, 2- and 3-bit buses, the first 2 are OK, but the 3-bit conversion gives an error:

```
cmd = B_TO_UINT1(1);          // line_1
cmd = B_TO_UINT2(1, 0);       // line_2
cmd = B_TO_UINT3(0, 1, 1);    // line_3
```

Build errors on `line_3`:

`warning C4003: not enough actual parameters for macro 'B_TO_UINT1'`

`error C2059: syntax error : '<<'`

So, looks like the `__VA_ARGS__` part is not expanding correctly with the recursion. Is this really the case? If so, is there a workaround?

Comment: Take `bxx` things into parentheses.

Comment: @EugeneSh. - thanks. Generally a good tip, but it does not solve this particular problem (I am getting other, `)` related error message). Anyway, in the actual code I cannot use parentheses from other reasons.

Comment: "*.. Anyway, in the actual code I cannot use parentheses from other reasons..*" In this case the code has some problem. Anyway, what message are you getting?

Comment: BTW, can't reproduce: https://ideone.com/8BHOi4

Comment: OK, I think I got the cause - this seems to be an MSVC bug, and I actually commented on a question dealing with it just earlier...: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26464843/274579

Comment: However, before making this observation a self-answer, I am waiting for confirmation on that from knowledgeable users.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134523/msvc-doesnt-expand-va-args-correctly

Comment: I don't know what this macro does, but maybe change `B_TO_UINT2` to `(((uint32_t) b01 << 1) | B_TO_UINT1(b01))`

Comment: @BarmakShemirani - it is (supposed to be) doing a conversion from a collection of discrete bits to an integer, as described. Doing as you suggest will just move the problem one step up in the cascade.

Comment: @EugeneSh. - the actual code is more complex in that it concatenates more stuff to the arg name and calls a (C++) method. It is probably easy to wrap the parens in the right place, just not around the arg name itself. Anyway, this is not the problem.

Comment: Check if you can use C++14 (or is it C++11) binary literals, like `0b101010`.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf - good to know 0bXX was formally added to the language. It was overlooked since K&R days... However, the actual code involves variables, not literals, so I am not sure how this will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, MS VC++ behaves differently than expected with the recursive expansion of `__VA_ARGS__` that includes multiple comma-separated arguments. When expanded in a nested macro, the the compiler treats the whole arg list as one argument.

Examples can also be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5134523/274579) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26467589/274579).

However, [@Ise Wisteria](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5134656/274579%5C) suggested the `EXPAND(x)` macro as a workaround. Using this tip, I changed my code to:

```
#define EXPAND( x ) x
#define B_TO_UINT1(b00)      (((uint32_t) b00 << 0))
#define B_TO_UINT2(b01, ...) (((uint32_t) b01 << 1) | EXPAND( B_TO_UINT1(__VA_ARGS__)))
#define B_TO_UINT3(b02, ...) (((uint32_t) b02 << 2) | EXPAND( B_TO_UINT2(__VA_ARGS__)))
#define B_TO_UINT4(b03, ...) (((uint32_t) b03 << 3) | EXPAND( B_TO_UINT3(__VA_ARGS__)))
// ...
```

Now the build errors are eliminated.

Note: I am not explicitly saying "a bug", b/c there may be a place for understanding the standard the MS way, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7459803/274579).